# Emacs multiple-cursor - Cut and yank in multiple lines

Tags: emacs

Using the 'multiple-cursor' emacs package,

when I mark a word and cut ('C-w') in different multiple cursors, the only word in the 'active' cursor I control is cut.

I want to select different words in multiple positions and yank it to other relative position.

When I first tried this I remember some yes or no option at the screen bottom, but I couldn't really notice this at first and some keystroke made it to "no". I guess this might have been an option for multiple-cut. But I don't know how to revert this choice.

How do you do multiple cut and yank in emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works by default, so at some point you have indeed asked the library not do do this.

These settings are stored (by default) in `~/.emacs.d/.mc-lists.el`

Just edit that file appropriately, and then <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd> to make those same changes in the running instance.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed the settings file and re-set everything and it works fine!